Blazor web app using .net 8 (server & client) 404 error => cors error
I discover a strange behavior on blazor .net 8. When you try to access to a wrong address from your blazor app, you will be redirected to a 404 page. However, if you have SignalR, it will not reconnect unless you exit the browser completly.
How to reproduce?

Create a server and wasm app using visual studio
Create a console project with signalr.
Specify the signalr project dependence to your server project
Add you signal connection protocol on the home component
Launch the app
When the home page is loaded, type a reference to your blazor app page which does not exist in the browser. You will experience the behavior specified in the intro.

I can provide if necessary a sample project. Did not post any project on my git related to this yet.
If you know how to resolve this behavior, please let me know.
I tried to use a console app for signalr because I am using the same hub for .net maui app and blazor web app.

Hi Flaubert TAGU, please share the sample project, so that we can know the issue clearly, then we can investigate the issue, thanks~

Ok. As soon as I get to office I will provide one for the community.

@JasonPan You can follow the link of the demo I create to demonstrate the fetch error issue here BlazorAppError404. Just run the Blazor server app. Instructions are filled in the home page.

Manually to recover the connection to signalR you need to open the devtools on the browser and delete the local resources 'blazor-resource-hash'. But no user will ever do that even if the know how to fix it. I wonder how we developers can solve this issue without asking the intervention of the user.

Hi Flaubert, Please kindly check the answer below, and I also want share my findings with you.  When we click the botton and we can find the url will change to https://localhost:7142//doesnotexist. The correct url should be https://localhost:7142/doesnotexist without double /. Then it will redirect to 404 page normally.

For checking your issue, I am using allow all origins in your project.
services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
{
    builder.AllowAnyMethod()
        .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials();
}));
...
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
...

Then I change your Home.razor page like below and it works in my side.
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager Navigation

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>404 Test Page</h1>
<p>
    Click on this button to navigate to a web page which does not exist.
    <br />
    In the program.cs for the Blazor server project, a specific page for 404 error has been specified.
    <br />
    <a href="@(Navigation.BaseUri + "doesnotexist")" class="btn btn-warning">Navigate to page not referenced</a>
</p>

@if (hub.IsConnected)
{
    <p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ReceiveRandomMessage">Random message from hub</button>
    </p>
}
else
{
    <p>Connecting to the server...</p>
}

<div style="border: 1px solid gray; border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px">
    <p>
        Connection status: <b>@hub.IsConnected</b>
    </p>
    <strong>Hub messages</strong>
    <hr />
    @foreach (var item in hub.Messages)
    {
        <p>- @item;</p>
    }
</div>

@code {
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            hub.InitHub();
            if (hub.hubConnection != null)
            {
                await hub.ConnectAsync();
                await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task ReceiveRandomMessage()
    {
        if (hub.IsConnected)
        {
            await hub.ReceiveRandomMessage();
            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hub is not connected yet.");
        }
    }
}

Test Result



your solution works thanks you. There is only one instance where it does not work for me. It is when I click on the button 'Return to home page' in the 404 page instead of clicking on the 'Home' link in the navbar. Other than that it works perfectly.

I found a more global solution. the only thing is that for some type of application architecture, it could be troublesome.
In the .csproj file of the client, I added the following:
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BlazorCacheBootResources>false</BlazorCacheBootResources>
  </PropertyGroup>

Without any other type of additional code it works perfectly.
